# How to mark questions as answered which are answered in comments?

Tags: discussion

In two cases my questions were answered in comments.  How to mark these questions as answered?

I could copy the comment to an answer and mark the answer as accepted but since the answer is'nt mine this seems strange.

In the case of these two questions it would also help to mark them as obsolete because in one case magit got a then new feature, in the other case it was a bug in magit which was closed a day before I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

A normal approach to this is to ask the author of the comment to post their comment again as an answer, and then mark it as an answer. This happened to me multiple times, and I got used to it. Copying someone else's answer might not get you in trouble, but it's nicer to let someone have the reputation they deserve for their answer.

If your question became obsolete, an answer stating that and giving relevant links (preferably marked as an answer) is a good approach. The question should not be deleted, as some people use older versions of Emacs and other packages, and it will serve as a reminder for them to update.

Comment: In one case it was a bug in a never released version of magit which lasted only a few days.  Can I delete the question?

Comment: It's up to you, really. It might be better to delete the question.